# Filter Option from a sequence in scala in effective way

Tags: list, scala

I want to get rid of `.isDefined` and `.get`, any good suggestions

```
 val t = Seq(Option("abc"), Option("def"), Option("abc"), Option(""))
 t.filter(_.isDefined).groupBy(x =>x.get)
```

I need my return type as `Map[String, Seq[String]]`

Comment: what if the point of `groupBy` in this code? Do you actually need a Map of something? It would be helpful if you explained what you were trying to achieve. To remove any `None`s you can just do `t.flatten` but most operations on collections will actually filter out `None` so if you explained your goal, maybe there is a better way

Comment: @sinanspd yes I need a map

Comment: @sinanspd flatten returns `Map[Nothing, Seq[Option[String]]`

Comment: `flatten` is not going to work here on it's own because it will also remove the `Some`. You can either do something like `t.flatten.groupMap(x => x)(Some(_))` or you have to define your own accumulation logic with `foldLeft`

Comment: @sinanspd does flattern helps to get rid of None ?

Comment: It does but it gets rid of `Option` all together. So `List(None, Some(1), Some(2), None).flatten` will return `List(1,2)`

Comment: Oh I guess you don't need the `Option` in the return type. In that case you can just do `t.flatten.groupBy(x=>x)`

Comment: @sinanspd I still get empty `Map(abc -> List(abc, abc), def -> List(def), "" -> List(""))`

Comment: Well you just changed your question entirely... The original question was how to get rid of `isDefined` and `.get`. The code you provided doesn't get rid of the empty string either. `Option("")` is **not** None. Empty string is still a valid value. You have no choice but to explicitly filter for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to `filter` and `map` at the same time, you can `collect`:

```
t.collect { case Some(s) if s.nonEmpty => s }.groupBy(identity)
```

The result of this is

```
Map("abc" -> Seq("abc", "abc"), "def" -> List("def"))
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/ZhQK5WMiTtGGRtjZbjLjHg/12).

You can read more about `collect` [here on the official documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.7/scala/collection/Seq.html#collect%5BB%5D(pf:PartialFunction%5BA,B%5D):CC%5BB%5D).

Comment: got it , my actual use case seems different from what I posted, I will create another thread

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69898936/filter-sequence-of-option-in-scala-equivalent-without-isdefined