# Filter Sequence of Option in scala equivalent without isDefined

Tags: scala

I want to get rid of `isDefined` and `get`

```
val t = Seq(A(Option("abc")), A(Option("abc")), A(Option("abc")), A(None))
t.filter(_.x.isDefined).groupBy(e=>e.x.get)
```

The code is complex , result I need is `Map[String,Seq[String]]`

Comment: What is the expected result? Also, what is the point of `A` if it just a wrapper over a single `Option`; I am sure your code is even more complex than this; so please provide all the relevant details and be clearer about what is the end result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could groupBy `x` instead of `x.get` and then flatMap the result to filter out the `None` group and extract the value from the `Some`s in one go.

```scala
t.groupBy(_.x).flatMap{ case (keyOpt, value) => keyOpt.map(_ -> value) }
```

That has the same effect as the code you posted. However if you want a `Map[String,Seq[String]]` instead of a `Map[String,Seq[A]]` you could do this instead:

```scala
t.flatMap(_.x).groupBy(identity)
```

Though grouping by identity might be a bit weird unless your ultimate goal is simply to count:

```scala
t.flatMap(_.x).groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)
```

Answer (score 1):

So assuming all you want is a `Map[String, Seq[String]]` where the values are just the same key over and over again; you can do this:

```scala
t.collect {
  case A(Some(x)) if x.nonEmpty => x
}.groupBy(identity)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `A` is a `case class` with a single parameter of optional type.
You can get the same result using the `partial functions` like

```
object FilterSeqOfOption extends App {

  case class A(x : Option[String])
  val t = Seq(A(Option("abc")), A(Option("abc")), A(Option("abc")), A(None))

 val res = t.collect { case A(Some(x)) => A(Option(x))
  }.groupBy{case A(Some(v)) => v}

  println(res)
}
```

Here collect first check whether `partial function` works for given value or not.